# Python Celery task workflow excution

Tags: python, canvas, error-handling, celery

I am new to Python Celery and trying to use Celery for a workflow execution. Workflow: [Task workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV7nf.png)

In the attached image, I have tried to show the workflow which is explained below in text.

1. A client invokes Task-1.
2. On success of Task-1, Task-2 and Task-3 are executed (simultaneously) and Task-4 is executed if Task-1 fails.
3. On success of Task-2, Task-5 and Task-6 are executed (simultaneously) and Task-7 is executed if Task-2 fails.
4. On success of Task-5, large number (100s) of Task-8 are executed (simultaneously) and Task-9 is executed if Task-5 fails.

When a client calls the Task-1, it passes one argument which is required to pass to next tasks in success and failure scenarios.

I understood that Canvas can be used to design a workflow with Celery. But, I am not able to make out how to proceed with such a big workflow with different layers of success and failures. Please suggest how should I use Celery and Canvas to plan such a workflow.
Any link for tutorial or example will be a great help as well.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this? (pseudo code)

```
workflow = (t1.s().set(link_error=t4.s()) | 

            group((t2.s().set(link_error=t7.s()) |

                   group(t6.s(),
                        (t5.s().set(link_error=t9.s()) |
                         group(t8.s(i) for i in xrange(100)))),

                  t3.s())
            )
).apply_async()
```

link_error is the callback for errors.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

Comment: The problem is not so much with launching ("calling") tasks within a task but with *waiting* for a task within a task (usually this will mean also launching it). The warning on [this page](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html) is clear. Unfortunately, the documentation [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks) talks of "launching synchronous subtasks". It may lead to think the "launching" part is the problem but really the problem is "synchronous", which implies waiting for the task. Lee's answer has no waits.

Comment: "if task_two(arg_one)": This should wait for the task to end. 
The question is pretty explicit about the workflow. See image. The tasks are executed in sequence if they previous task succeeds. I call this waiting, I am not sure what you mean by "has no waits"

Comment: Calling a task like you show (`task_two(...)`) completely bypasses workers. It is the `__call__` method described [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html): "means that the task will be executed in the current process, and not by a worker (a message will not be sent)." There is no waiting involved. If you want to call this "synchronous", then fine, but it is is not the "synchronous" that is discussed in the Celery documentation I mentioned earlier. *That* synchronous is about having a task *run by a worker* and immediately *waiting* for it.

Comment: I see. I will correct my answer. I thought that  task_two(arg) was some pseudocode equivalent to task_two().get().

Answer (score 1):

You can have a wrapper task that handles the logic of calling the other tasks.

Your code might end up something like this.

```
@celery.task(name='tasks.wrapper_task')
def wrapper_task(one_arg):
    if task_one(one_arg):
        task_three.apply_async(arg_one)
        if task_two(arg_one):
            task_six.apply_async(arg_one)
            if task_five(arg_one): 
                task_eight.apply_async(1)
                task_eight.apply_async(2)
                # etc...
            else:
                task_nine(arg_one)
        else:
            task_seven(arg_one)
    else:
        task_four(arg_one)
```

I haven't defined all the tasks for you. As you can see, not all need to even be celery tasks unless you need to call them asynchronously in other situations.

I've taken 'fail' to mean returns falsy, but you could easily adapt the code to use `try` / `except`.

Comment: Thanks Lee for the idea of wrapper task.